# Using JavaScript to stream audio via webKitAudioContext

Tags: javascript, audio, audio-streaming, html5-audio, webkitaudiocontext

I am trying to access my computer's audio source in order to stream to a back end server. I am using the tutorial [found here](http://www.smartjava.org/content/record-audio-using-webrtc-chrome-and-speech-recognition-websockets) which uses a `webKitAudioContext` object to facilitate this connection.

I'm confused by the `stream` object, however. First off, in the `webkitGetUserMedia` method, the `callback` function is called without this parameter. Second, the instructions on the web page read

`"We ask, using getUserMedia, for access to the microphone. If this is successful our callback gets called with the audio stream as its parameter."`

Can anyone tell me what this `stream` variable is/where it is supposed to come from? This is my first foray into streaming audio, so sorry if this is a n00b question. :)

```
      function callback(stream) {
           var context = new webkitAudioContext();
           var mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
           ...
       }

       $(document).ready(function() {
           navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, callback);
           ...
       }
```

**EDIT**

Apparently this is some sort of "implied" parameter that evaluates to the following in the console:

```
LocalMediaStream {onremovetrack: null, onaddtrack: null, onended: null, ended: false, id: "zr0ZH5b0YZy6gjTGyaKdncl5XYFYT2LsAEPS"…}
```

I'm still new to this whole streaming thing, so anyone with some more info on what this object is I'd much appreciate it. Thanks!